# How to build data for a SCNGeometrySource in Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I try to build a SCNGeometrySource in swift.

I want to use the `SCNGeometrySource(data: Data, semantic: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic, vectorCount: Int, usesFloatComponents: Bool, componentsPerVector: Int, bytesPerComponent: Int, dataOffset: Int, dataStride: Int)` initializer, because I have already a buffer giving vertex position, normal and colors - or at least, I can build it.

But how do I transform my buffer into a Data type (for the data parameter) ?

Using `Data(bytesNoCopy: buffer as! UnsafeMutableRawPointer ...)` gives me a warning that the cast will fail (and I believed it).

I have also tried with no success to use `Data.append(xxx)`functions, but there is no way I could find to just cast the address of my larger buffer into an UnsafePointer of any kind (and it also implies an additional copy of the large buffer).

So what's the way ?

Edit: the "large buffer" is a concatenation of

```
struct VertexInfo {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    var z: Float
    var nx: Float
    var ny: Float
    var nz: Float
    var a: Float
    var r: Float
    var g: Float
    var b: Float
}
```

I can provide it under any type, but for the time being, I build it with a `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<VertexInfo>`

Comment: What is the type of `buffer`?

Comment: Edit in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the solved the problem : I used an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to allocate the "large buffer" directly using `malloc()` and build the `Data` using `Data(bytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:)`which does not imply yet another copy of the data.

Now, to fill the "large buffer", I used a `UnsafeMutablePointer<VertexInfo>` to make it easy, but the secret is to make the UnsafeMutablePointer pointing to the large buffer using `bindMemory(to:capacity:)`.

This way, the UnsafeMutableRawPointer and the UnsafeMutablePointer actual point to the same buffer. The UnsafeMutablePointer can be used to easily fill the buffer with the data, and the UnsafeMutableRawPointer can be easily used to create the Data.

```
// Assuming VertexInfo type holds the information for a vertex
// Assuming we have vectorMaxCount as the number of vertices we want

// Compute the size of the buffer to allocate
var size       = vectorMaxCount * MemoryLayout<VertexInfo>.stride
// Allocate the buffer as a UnsafeMutableRawPointer
var buffer     = malloc(size)
// Create a UnsafeMutablePointer<VertexInfo> that points to the allocated buffer
var vertexList = buffer!.bindMemory(to: VertexInfo.self, capacity: vectorMaxCount)

// Fill the buffer with the needed data
for index in 0..< vectorMaxCount {
    let vertex = // Compute here your vertex info as a VertexInfo
    // Easily fill the buffer thanks to the UnsafeMutablePointer<VertexInfo>
    vertexList[index] = vertex
}

// Create the Data thanks to the UnsafeMutableRawPointer
let data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: size, freeWhenDone: true) as Data
```

Note that the ownership of the buffer is given to data thanks to the `freeWhenDone: true` parameter.

This is quite generic and can be used to build any compacted buffer of data, not only for SceneKit.